# HTML button in php file

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

I have a wordpress website and I created a child theme so that I can make changes.  Here's the issue:

There's a template page and it's a PHP page.  Inside that template I wanted to add an extra button with a link and a css class so that I can customize it.

The button shows up just fine on the page, but it can't be clicked.  Clicking on it does nothing.  I've tried using echo, print, and a host of other approaches.

This is the html code I'm using to create the button:

```
<a href="https://www.beat-tweaks.com/academy" class="membership-button">ACADEMY MEMBERHIP: $19.99/MONTH</a>
```

Here's some of the code from the file itself:

```
<div class="course5-pricing" id="course-pricing">
<?php bp_course_credits(); ?>
<?php the_course_button(); ?>
<a href="https://www.beat-tweaks.com/academy" class="membership-button">ACADEMY MEMBERHIP: $19.99/MONTH</a>
<?php
add_filter('wplms_course_details_widget',function($args) 
{unset($args['price']); return $args;})?>
</div>

        <div class="course-pricing">
            <?php the_course_details(); ?>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
<?php
do_action( 'bp_after_course_header' );
?>
```

What's even more confusing is that I have a wordpress site setup locally on my MAC, and this all works perfectly fine.  But when i try it on my live site, it doesn't work anywmore.

Comment: You need to provide a [mcve]. Since the problem is with how the final HTML is rendered, you need to show us the relevant HTML, CSS and JS (testing to making sure that what you provide actually demonstrates the problem!) but the PHP that generates it isn't useful.

Comment: Hey Quentin.  Here is a page that has the button on it
https://www.beat-tweaks.com/course/mastering-edm-with-fabfilter/

The button in question is the one that says "Academy Membership."  To view its HTML, you actually have to first inspect the button above it (red button) since you can't even inspect it for some reason.

The CSS is as follows:
    a.membership-button {
    background-color: #444444;
    border: none;
    color: white;
    padding: 15px 32px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 14px;
    }

Comment: Your `#content` element overlaps your side block, give the former a background color, then you can easily see it. You have some sort of z-index issue here, probably due to the combination with `transform: translateY(…)`

Comment: @04FS I suspect you're right.  When I remove the content area I can actually click on the button.  But I'm not really sure what to do with the transform:translate or how I need to adjust the #content

EDIT:  changed the z-index of the #content and it solved the issue.  THANK YOU

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update your code as pare this. here I added  two inline CSS you can use this CSS form your external CSS file that's good practice

I have updated your  `<div class="w3-center w3-small w3-opacity" style="  position: relative;    z-index: 3;">`

and `<a href="https://www.beat-tweaks.com/academy" class="membership-button" >ACADEMY MEMBERHIP: $19.99/MONTH</a>`

if you want to open at same windows you can remove  `target="_blank"` from updated code

```html
<div class="w3-center w3-small w3-opacity" style="  position: relative;    z-index: 3;">
<?php bp_course_credits(); ?>
<?php the_course_button(); ?>
   <a href="https://www.beat-tweaks.com/academy" class="membership-button" target="_blank" style="
        display: block;
        clear: both;
        z-index: 9999;
        background: gray;
        color: white;
        width: 200px;
        height: 40px 
    ">ACADEMY MEMBERHIP: $19.99/MONTH</a>
<?php
add_filter('wplms_course_details_widget',function($args) 
{unset($args['price']); return $args;})?>
</div>

        <div class="course-pricing">
            <?php the_course_details(); ?>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
<?php
do_action( 'bp_after_course_header' );
?>
```